# button onclick crash when no value insert

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

everything works perfect just when the user click on the button but no value in the editText the app cruse.

I take the editText value and put it in a String , then I take the String and put it in Double.

here is the code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText editText;
    EditText editTextw;
    TextView textView7;
    TextView textView8;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editTextw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.with);

        textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        final Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String height = editText.getText().toString();
                String weight = editTextw.getText().toString();

                Double hh = Double.parseDouble(height);
                Double w = Double.parseDouble(weight);

                Double h = hh/100;
                Double all = (w  / (h * h));

                Double number2 = (int)Math.round(all * 100)/(double)100;


                textView8.setText("BMI: " + number2);
                textView8.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));



                if (all < 18.5) {
                    textView7.setText("תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' +  "\"תת משקל\" ");
                    textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
                } else if (all > 18.5 && all < 25.0) {
                    textView7.setText("תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' + "\"משקל בריא\" ");
                    textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

                }else if (all > 25.0 && all < 30.0) {
                    textView7.setText(" תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' + "\"עודף משקל\"");
                    textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

                }else if (all > 30.0) {
                    textView7.setText(" תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' + " \"השמנת יתר\"");
                    textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

                }else  {
                textView7.setText(" תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' + " \"השמנת יתר\"");
                textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

            }

            }
        });


        }
        }
```

here is the activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dor.maby.MainActivity"
    android:background="#FF5722"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="חשב BMI "
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="#FF7043"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="גובה"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />

        <EditText
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:hint="@string/hint1"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="משקל"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />


        <EditText
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/with"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#E3F2FD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#E3F2FD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably crashing at that moment because parseDouble fails on anything but numbers. My suggestion would be to check for empty string and is it is an empty string don't parse and make your double a default value.

Comment: Can you tell me how i do it?

Comment: I won't write everything but you should get everything off this.
`if(height.equals(""))
{
     hh = <some default value>;
}
else
{
     hh = Double.parseDouble(height);
} `

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check on the value of the Edittext before running your onclick code 
i.e

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{

if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !editTextw.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
  String height = editText.getText().toString();
  String weight = editTextw.getText().toString();
  .... REST of onclick code ....
}
else
{
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "Fill in both texts!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: my mistake I meant to use the EditText.getText().toString() changed my answer as such

Comment: I would suggest using the .isEmpty() function then which is actually what I use I think I should go to bed.

Comment: Thank @Mike M for keeping me on my toes you can mark the answer as correct too!!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the height and weight variables are null be for using them. I'd create a helper method to do the check. For example:

```
  //helper method to check if String has null value
  private boolean checkNull(String value){
     return (value != null && !value.isEmpty());
  }
```

Then in your onClick method you can do the following;

```
String height = editText.getText().toString().trim();
String weight = editTextw.getText().toString().trim();

if(checkNull(height) && checkNull(weight) ){
    Double hh = Double.parseDouble(height);
    Double w = Double.parseDouble(weight);
}else{
    //make toast with error message
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this way

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText editText;
    EditText editTextw;
    TextView textView7;
    TextView textView8;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editTextw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.with);

        textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        final Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String height = editText.getText().toString();
                String weight = editTextw.getText().toString();

                if(height!=null && weight!=null && !height.equals("") && !weight.equals(""))
                {
                Double hh = Double.parseDouble(height);
                Double w = Double.parseDouble(weight);

                Double h = hh/100;
                Double all = (w  / (h * h));

                Double number2 = (int)Math.round(all * 100)/(double)100;


                textView8.setText("BMI: " + number2);
                textView8.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

                 }

                if (all < 18.5) {
                    textView7.setText("תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' +  "\"תת משקל\" ");
                    textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
                } else if (all > 18.5 && all < 25.0) {
                    textView7.setText("תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' + "\"משקל בריא\" ");
                    textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

                }else if (all > 25.0 && all < 30.0) {
                    textView7.setText(" תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' + "\"עודף משקל\"");
                    textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

                }else if (all > 30.0) {
                    textView7.setText(" תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' + " \"השמנת יתר\"");
                    textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

                }else  {
                textView7.setText(" תוצאה זאת מכניסה אותך לקטגוריה של" +'\n' + " \"השמנת יתר\"");
                textView7.setTypeface(textView7.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                textView7.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));

            }

            }
        });


        }
        }
```